# c# assign the highest id of an access database to a variable

Tags: c#, max, oledb

I'm a 100% that the issue I'm about to describe must have got someday an answer. But I haven't been clever enough to find it out in stackoverflow. So, sorry guys to ask again. But if you have a link for someone's post who got that issue resolved, I'll take it !

Here's a piece of the c# code I'm struggling with for the moment:

```
OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\MyAccessDB.accdb");

string strReq = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(FIELD_ID as Int)),0) + 1 FROM TBL_TABLE";
cnx.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strReq, cnx);
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
   int intId = (int)dr["FIELD_ID"];
}

cmd.Dispose();
cnx.Close();
```

That piece of code is supposed to assign the max value + 1 to the FIELD_ID of the access table TBL_TABLE. But I have an issue on line #5 !!! I'm really out of ideas... Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Autonumber fields are the usual way to have an incrementing value and prevent the problem you will probably have if multiple people run this query at the same time.  You should perhaps explain what you are trying to achieve with `intId`.

Comment: Please also add the error you are encountering. Access does not support `CAST()`.

Comment: You would need to alias that statement in mssql. Not sure about access. SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(FIELD_ID as Int)),0) + 1 AS FIELD_ID

Comment: Alex K & Nikki9696, thans a lot for your help !!! Thank you very much for your constructive help !!! Indeed, now I plainly realize ACCESS hates CAST, ISNULL! and I have the feeling that I'm about to 'meet' many other surprises with ACCESS ! Honestly, I thought that M$ would have the descent idea of adding some SQLSERVER functions to ACCESS, and finally, I was wrong!!! That's where my issues came from. So, finally, the good code (following your wise advice) is the following :

Comment: OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\MyAccessDB.accdb");
string strReq = "SELECT MAX(FIELD_ID) AS ID FROM TBL_TABLE";
cnx.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strReq, cnx);

OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


if (dr.Read())

{

    int intId = (int)dr["ID"];

}


cmd.Dispose();

cnx.Close();

Comment: How can I specify that this post is finally resolved?

Comment: You can wait a while then accept your own answer below by clicking the tick mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again to Alex K & Nikki9696, here's the good working code:

```
OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\MyAccessDB.accdb");
string strReq = "SELECT MAX(FIELD_ID) AS ID FROM TBL_TABLE";
cnx.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strReq, cnx);
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
    int intId = (int)dr["ID"];
}

cmd.Dispose();
cnx.Close();
```

Comment: If `Field_ID` is an auto-incrementing field, and is indexed (both of which are usually true for Xxxx_ID fields in a normal database (I haven't used Access in decades), then you can do something like `Select top (1) Field_ID from Tbl_Table order by Field_ID DESC`